# RegExp (preg_match) for variables

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to match the variables out of a script, for example this line:

```
Hello World, this is a Test. $i = 1, $sString = "Test"
```

So I want to get **$i** and **$sString**.

I tried many different patterns, e.g. `$pattern = '/(\$\w+)/';`. I only get **$i** twice but not **$sString**.

As you can see [here](http://james1337.bplaced.net/re_test.php).

Comment: and remove capturing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get one match `$i`. The reason that there are two results is that the parentheses [capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the result and that capture is returned as well (you could use this to return submatches, like everything except the leading `$`). To get all matches, use `preg_match_all`. And remove the parentheses if you don't need them (and you'll never need them if they just wrap the entire expression):

```
preg_match_all('/[$]\w+/', $subject, $matches);
```

Note that the resulting array is one level deeper, so you'll find your array of matches in `$matches[0]`.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/IbkCsR)